# Incremental image pulling in a scholl with windows

Tags: windows, wds, image, client-server, pool

This is hard for me. I am a teacher at a school and I have to manage the PC room and mobile notebook classrooms. I use GNU/Linux privately, so I am basically a beginner in windows network administration.

I need the following:

- I manually manage a windows client, update the software etc. and write an image of this client and put in  on the server
- Whenever a student boots up a PC in the pool, the image is pulled from the server, preferably incrementally to save traffic, and booted.
- any changes the student makes is saved to his own user directory on the server and never on the image, so all acts of vandalism can be reset by rebooting.

Please give me a few directions on how to achieve this. Could I use WDS for this? Would you suggest any other solutions? Can windows clients even be managed this way or will the registry and/or the activation be problematic?

Comment: Your choices are basically Intune or Active Directory. But this seems like something the school district IT department should be doing. If you have a school district, of course.

Comment: I work in a german school. Basically, the school IT has to be financed by the school's budget. Do you have any link for me to read on?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/introduction-intune and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/introduction-intune-education